# Jquery each not pulling all elements with the selected class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a page with a search box and 5 Boostrap Cards. I made it so that the cards should hide if you search in the box and the text doesn't match text within the `data-tags` attribute. It works, except it doesn't pull the cards. It only pulls the cards under the first `card-deck` container. It ignores all cards under the second one. I intentionally made the data-tags attribute as "nothing" and then tried searching:

[image]

[image]

I made a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/perezdev/krdgmuf4/7/

If you search for "isol", only the first card should appear, as that phrase matches the attribute:

[image]

Here is the core of the JS/Jquery:

```
$(".card").each(function () {
    var tags = $(this).attr('data-tags');

    if (tags !== undefined && tags !== null) {
      var matchIndex = tags.indexOf(text);
      if (matchIndex > -1) {
        $(this).show();
      }
      else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
  });
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try putting `data-tags` on the `card` element instead of the `card-deck` element. The current code reads this attribute from the `card`:

```
$(".card").each(function () {
    var tags = $(this).attr('data-tags');
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm a dummy. I corrected it and it works. Thanks for the help.